# How do I synchronize ArrangeOverride with my animations?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a drag and drop implementation where I animate items which are below the dragged item.
The problem is that the animation of an item below can still be running when I drop the dragged item.

This leads to a call to ArrangeOverride which resets the item below position and then my Storyboard.Completed call moves the item again which leads to a wrong positioning.

```
Reanimate below: 1: Direction: 200
Reanimate dragged: 0: Direction: -200
Complete on dragged item: 0: Direction: -200
ArrangeOverride
ArrangeOverride Done
Complete on itembelow: 1: Direction: 200
```

Is there a way to synchronize the ArrangeOverride call with my animation to that it is called when the animation is done?

My code is a modified version of https://github.com/realistschuckle/wpfchrometabs which has the same problem